# why can we increment the dereferenced pointer to a constant data in C++?

Tags: c++, pointers

I was surprised that c++ allows incrementing dereferenced pointer to a constant data, which it should not allow through a pointer to a const data. Consider the code:

```
#include<iostream>
#include<climits>
using namespace std;

int main(){
    int x = 2;

    const int *xPtr2 = &x;
    *xPtr2++;
    cout << x << endl;

}
```

But still the value of x is 2. That means *xPtr2 was not actually incremented. I also tried *xPtr2 = 3, but this time it shows compilation error. Why is it so?

Comment: Try the same thing with `int * const xPtr2 = &x`.

Comment: Undefined behaviour to increment a pointer like this. You can only increment to one element past the end of an array. This isn't an array and simply incrementing the pointer is already undefined before you even get the chance to dereference it.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Here the precedence of ++ is more than that of *. Hence

```
*xPtr2++
```

is equivalent to

```
*(xPtr2++)
```

Since xPtr2 is not a constant pointer but a pointer to constant data, incrementing xPtr2 and dereferencing it is fine in this case (but not others) and hence no compilation error is caused.

Comment: Dereferencing isn't exactly "perfectly fine" since it's undefined.

Answer (score 2):

The `++` operator has precedence over dereferencing. Basically you're dereferencing the pointer that has been incremented.

For the behavior you're trying to accomplish, you should wrap the pointer in parens.

```
(*xPtr2)++;
```

Same goes for assigning - you're trying to assign an `int` to a `int *`. It would work with parens.

```
(*xPtr2) = 3;
```

See [your example in ideone](https://ideone.com/2l3stk).

Answer (score 0):

You have mentioned

> dereferencing pointer to constant data

So, lets consider the following code

```c
#include <stdio.h>
int main() {
    const int foo = 0xdead;
    int* bar = (int*) &foo;
    *bar = 0xcafe;
    printf("const int foo = %#x", foo);
    return 0;
}
```

Output : `const int foo = 0xcafe`

In C, C++ `const` is just a ***compile time modifier*** for variables. This means that the compiler wants no modification to a `const` at compile time. At runtime there is no concept of `const` => all local variables are stored in stack, all `static` and global variables are stored in `.data` section. Thus you can dereference a const and modify it only at **runtime**